# Upload big file with Jackrabbit WebDAV Library on Android

Tags: android

My upload function as below:

```
public void WebdavPutFile() {
    try {
        PutMethod Upload = new PutMethod("http://URL/FileName");
        File f = new File("Path");
        if(f.exists()) {
            RequestEntity requestEntity = new InputStreamRequestEntity(new FileInputStream(f));
            Upload.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
            client.executeMethod(Upload);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It can upload small file success.
But if file size large than 16mb, it will occurs outofmemory issue.
How can I do to upload big file?

Comment: The issue is that it is loading the whole file into memory. Instead you need to use a Multipart-form request. I haven't used this specific library, but hopefully it will get you on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer from [here](http://ashimita.blogspot.tw/2011/05/using-jackrabbit-as-webdav-client-for.html).

Use `FileRequestEntity` instead of `InputStreamRequestEntity`.
It works for big file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Heap is exploding when you are loading large files. :)

From what I have read [here](http://www.webdavsystem.com/javaserver/doc/resumable_upload/how_it_works) it is possible to create resumable upload to the WebDav server. All you have to do is read your large file with `RandomAccessFile` and create some buffer, let's say 1MB, and do several uploads to with the **header** specified in the link provided. If you need the code to split the file in chunks, let me know.